# Random colors on single objects and only for selected faces

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine

I want to have random colors for each face individually, it is possible?

How?
Now each faces have a same color...

I have attached here the .blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vlQhosnAhCxOwQyWxGnMagXtvAdIv_Gq/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: You need to use "geometry" node in shader -> Random Per Island socket, but first you need to add seams to determine those islands